# How can I store newline character in char variable?

Tags: java, char, newline

I want to store the newline character in a char variable in Java using the following line:

```
char newline = "/n";
```

My compiler returns the following:

> error: incompatible data types: String cannot be converted to char

how can I fix or work around this issue?

Comment: Use single quotes: `'\n'`.

Comment: maybe need to escape the newline character with backslash? `char newline = '\n';`

Comment: This shows that you haven't done any research. First of all, you obviously shouldn't use `"` for a char and secondly, using `/` for an escape sequence is also wrong. And even if you don't know the term "escape sequence", searching for "line ending char" is pretty easy.

Answer (score 7):

Use single quotes. i.e.

```
char newline = '\n';
```

Having said that, Java has a system property for storing the current OS's line break, `System.getProperty("line.separator");`, which returns a String.

Comment: You forgot to mention the need to use backslash instead of forward slash, @Powerlord.

Comment: @LewBloch True, but on the other hand at least I put it in the correct direction in the code block.

Comment: Yes, true, but the OP likely needed that called to their attention specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a `String` to be assigned to a `char`. That will never work. `String` literals are delineated with the double-quote character, `"`. Character literals are delineated with the *single*-quote character, `'`. In addition, you specified two characters in your string, not one. `'/'` is one character, and `'n'` is another. If you are trying to specify an escape sequence
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6
then you need to use the *backslash* character, not the forward slash: `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the incorrect escape character. Please replace it like

```
String s = "hello "+"\n";
```

please try and let me know if it helps.

Comment: What is `string`?

Comment: He asked about storing newline character in char variable, why do you even mention string?

Answer (score 0):

As per Oracle Java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

> Literals of types char and String may contain any Unicode (UTF-16)
>   characters. Always use 'single quotes' for char literals and "double
>   quotes" for String literals.

The escape sequences for char and string are as follows:
`\b (backspace), \t (tab), \n (line feed), \f (form feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double quote), \' (single quote), and \\ (backslash)`.

Therefore, if *newline* is of datatype *char* then use `char newline = '\n'`
Else if *newline* is of datatype *String* then use `String newline = "\n"`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to [@Powerlords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43461430/7028187) answer and mention that the line separator can, as of Java SE 7, be retrieved using System.lineSeparator() meaning you could just write:

```
String lineSep = System.lineSeparator();
```

Keep in mind that the `String` class **does not inherently exist as a primitive in Java** in contrast to `char` as it merely is a class of the standard Java libraries.

This solution is the best for maintaining consistency across Operating Systems as not all OS hold a line separator in a single byte slot (`char` variable).

Comment: `lineSeparator()` is a String not a char so this doesnt work